# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-hover'

Tags: reactjs

I installed the 'react-hover' library for my react code from https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover

I used the import statement like : `import ReactHover from 'react-hover';`

Then I am getting this error

*Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-hover'. 'd:/.......(path)/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-hover` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-hover';`ts(7016)*

When I tried `npm install @types/react-hover`,
it's also not working (Causing the following error)

*npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-hover@latest' is not in the npm registry.*

*npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because*

*npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters*

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This means that there currently are no type definitions available for that dependency, because the package owner/community didn't create those yet.

A quick fix would be to create a new declaration file (`declarations.d.ts`) in your project that contains `declare module 'react-hover';` just like the error states:

> Try npm install @types/react-hover if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-hover';

Note that does not add type checking to your project for this dependency!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `import * as ReactHover from "react-hover"` ? This is sometimes due to the use of typescript in some libraries.

Comment: The same problem exists when I tried as you said. I think @Potato said the reason for the issue